# Keeping tally of users who meet more than one condition

Tags: sql

I have a database of users (represented by visitorId) who belong to a specific channel and exhibited certain behaviors, as logged under the eCommerceActionType field.

| channel | visitorId | eCommerceActionType |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Social | 1 | page_view |
| Social | 1 | added_to_cart |
| Referral | 2 | added_to_cart |
| Referral | 2 | purchased |
| Social | 3 | page_view |
| Social | 3 | added_to_cart |
| Social | 3 | purchased |
| Direct | 4 | page_view |
| Direct | 4 | added_to_cart |

I want to output a table that keeps a tally of users who both "added_to_cart" and "purchased" by channel. So the result should look like:

| Channel | cart_and_purchase |
| --- | --- |
| Social | 1 |
| Referral | 1 |
| Direct | 0 |

What is the most efficient query to produce this table?

Appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: Please, show what the code do you have so far? What was wrong with it? You need just conditional count per user: one for the first condition, one for the second. Then in `having` clause you filter by `>0`. If you need total count per category, then you'll do another count over that query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use two levels of aggregation:

```
select channel,
       sum(case when num_added_to_cart > 0 and num_purchased > 0 then 1 else 0 end) as cart_and_purchase
from (select channel, visitorid,
             sum(case when eCommerceActionType = 'added_to_cart' then 1 else 0 end) as num_added_to_cart,
             sum(case when eCommerceActionType = 'purchased' then 1 else 0 end) as num_purchased
      from t
      group by channel, visitorid
     ) t
group by channel;
```